# Error in xml layout, Can't convert to dimension: 15

Tags: android, android-layout

Within my application I have an error in the graphical layout which shows up as:

```
error!
UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: 15
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogThe following classes could not be found:
- TextView
```

When I run the application this works, but it shows the error in the graphical layout, does anyone know the cause of this.

It occurs when I put `android:layout_marginTop="-3dip"` , if I dont use `-` then this doesn't show.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a negative margin.
Use `android:gravity="top"` if your textview is higher than your textsize and you want the text to appear on the top. Otherwise use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Your view will exactly fit this way.

If you want 3dp space between the top border of the textview and the actual text,
use `android:paddingTop="3dp"`. Generally, margin is the free space outside the view, padding is the inside spacing between the border and the content.

Comment: Actually negative margins can be used in LinearLayout.

Comment: @Romain can it not be used in RelativeLayout?

Comment: You can use negative margins in RelativeLayout too.

Comment: In a RelativeLayout, "-1dp" in attribute "layout_marginTop" is not a valid format. That's what the designer says.

Comment: @RomainGuy is this expected behaviour and only fixable with negative margins? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17525084/1322226

Comment: @RomainGuy can I expect a button to still be clickable after using negative margins to float it outside of a view?

Comment: @Sam no unless you mess with the tap event routing.

Comment: After a couple of years Romain Guy says "Negative margins have never been officially supported in RelativeLayout." https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212499

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you still need help with this problem; however, I ran into a similar message and thought I would share to hopefully help anyone else that might run into this error message.

I found that the error was **only** occurring in the "2.7in QVGA slider" device configuration.  I also found that if I changed the negative value to a different number I no longer got the error message.

So, I ended up using -2 instead.

I am going to guess the error is caused by some of the scaling calculations in the graphical renderer.  But it's not worth researching to find out at this point.