# How to provide support for Fragments and ActionBar for App which supports Android 2.2+ devices?

Tags: android

I have visited so many similar links like this i.e [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528691/fragments-in-android-2-2-1-2-3-2-0-is-this-possible), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176841/android-fragment-api-for-api-level-11)  followed various examples / links i.e. [this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) and [this one](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/) mainly I have followed this post from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial) that too multiple times, Every time I get same exception.... What could be the reason ?

```
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myexample.fragmentdemoexample/com.myexample.fragmentsupportexample.MainFragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at com.myexample.fragmentsupportexample.MainFragmentActivity.onCreate(MainFragmentActivity.java:14)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  ... 11 more
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myexample.fragmentdemoexample.MyListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-27 12:00:33.431: E/AndroidRuntime(663):  ... 21 more
```

**EDIT** Here is my full code
//MainActivity

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_fragment, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

//DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Need to check if Activity has been switched to landscape mode
        // If yes, finished and go back to the s tart Activity
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
                Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity_layout);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String s = extras.getString("value");
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
            view.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

//MyListFragment

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
                "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()).findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            fragment.setText(item);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", item);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
}
```

//DetailsFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String item) {
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        view.setText(item);
    }
}
```

//Layouts  are
//activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.myexample.fragmentdemoexample.MyListFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.myexample.fragmentdemoexample.DetailFragment" >

        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

//details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and code for layout-port is similar to as mentioned on Vogella's post with appropriate changes

Comment: post your code and layout file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293558/error-in-xml-layout-cant-convert-to-dimension-15 is this my problem ? checked but not sure about it...

Comment: http://www.sendspace.com/file/vdhx6w check out this demo, its your code without error

Comment: @AndroidCoader Thanks for your link... please post that as answer so that I can accept it.... 1000 thanks buddy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code is look good , just keep in mind that you have two xml file activity_main.xml one will be in layout folder and second will be in layout-port folder.

For complete working demo of Vogella check out this link project.

http://www.sendspace.com/file/vdhx6w

Comment: just delete layout-large-land folder, it just no use

Comment: i hope you will resolve your problem. I think it was a minor mistake

Comment: Why ViewPager is not swiping to next fragment... I think it should work as it is... Do I need to add something more... please help

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class MainPoP extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ListFragment.OnMainMenuListener{
    Button home;
    Button about;
    Button donate;
    Button explore;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    ListFragment mainMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mainMenu = new ListFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.mainView, mainMenu).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

THis is how i am making a fragment and its working just fine. Try using the OnCreateView method to inflate your fragment like this in the class which is extending Fragment or is the particular fragment which you want to set some layout:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_fragment, container, false);
    return v;
}
```